# Selenium Chrome Driver throws an exception

Tags: selenium

> Starting ChromeDriver 2.19.346078 (6f1f0cde889532d48ce8242342d0b84f94b114a1) on port 26562
>       Only local connections are allowed.
>       [1.391][SEVERE]: Unable to receive message from renderer
>       Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created exception
>       from disconnected: Unable to receive message from renderer
>         (Session info: chrome=61.0.3163.100)
>         (Driver info: chromedriver=2.19.346078 (6f1f0cde889532d48ce8242342d0b84f94b114a1),platform=Windows NT 10.0 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>       Command duration or timeout: 1.59 seconds
>       Build info: version: '2.51.0', revision: '1af067d', time: '2016-02-05 19:11:55'
>       System info: host: 'LT-BMAHESH', ip: '10.255.250.14', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
>       Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:249)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:144)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:170)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:159)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:116)
>           at SanityTests.CrossBrowser.main(CrossBrowser.java:25)

Comment: Update your chromedriver and try again. `2.19` is very old, the latest is `2.33`

Comment: upgrade chromedriver should fix your problem

Comment: i did the upgrade for my chrome driver to 2.33 and curently i am using 62x of chrome browser, Still it shows this error, [2.930][SEVERE]: Unable to receive message from renderer
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod launchBrowser
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created exception
from disconnected: Unable to receive message from renderer
  (Session info: chrome=62.0.3202.94)

Comment: I tried using various browsers of chrome and Selenium versions, Still, it doesn't work. I went down to 54x for chrome browser even.

Answer (score 0):

For this problem

> Starting ChromeDriver 2.19.346078 (6f1f0cde889532d48ce8242342d0b84f94b114a1) on port 26562 Only local connections are allowed. [1.391][SEVERE]: Unable to receive message from renderer Exception in thread "main

you need to download the latest version of chrome driver.Hope problem will be solved.
Download here https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

Comment: [2.930][SEVERE]: Unable to receive message from renderer
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod launchBrowser
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created exception
from disconnected: Unable to receive message from renderer
  (Session info: chrome=62.0.3202.94)     This error is seen again

Comment: I am using the Current Version of Chrome Driver from Seleniumhq.org which is 2.33 Version